# How do I obtain 100% coverage when an exception is thrown in a unit test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

In `C#` you can catch an exception in the default test suite like this:

```
[TestMethod]
[ExpectedException(typeof (ArgumentNullException))]
public void TestNullComposite()
{
    IApi api = new Api();
    api.GetDataUsingDataContract(null); // this method throws ArgumentNullException
}
```

But when you analyze the code coverage, it says that you only get 66.67% coverage because the last curly brace was not covered.

How would I go about achieving 100% coverage on this unit test?

Comment: You should analyze percentage of code, covered by tests. Not tests themself (I don't even understand what covers your tests)

Comment: But the problem with that is that then you are only exercising the code.  Test code can also have bugs that aren't exposed if you don't exercise it 100%, just like regular code.  Also, what's the point of having test code that doesn't run?

Comment: Also remember that coverage at the line-level is not a great metric, and is not entirely the point. The point is, what is the remaining risk of something really bad happening?

Comment: What happens if you reformat the test code so the curly brace is on the 3rd line? Just asking...

Comment: I'd be violating company coding standards. And also, you still don't get 100% coverage.

Comment: Does it mean, you have UnitTests#2 to test other UnitTests#1 and get 100% coverage on those UnitTests#1? And then another set of UnitTests#3 to get 100% coverage on UnitTests#2? Come on... Unit test should be simple enough that it doesn't require testing itself. If it's not, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Sounds like the coding standard contradicts the testing standard. This can only be resolved by making the two coincide at the same place and time, resulting in mutual annihilation or a further series of meetings, whichever is worse.

Comment: If you know the only reason for not getting 100% coverage is that the curly brace was missed...why does it matter as long as your tests are doing their job?

Comment: @stephen You don't have any "test code that doesn't run". You have a misleading coverage tool. What code do you think the closing brace generates?

Comment: @DNA - when I say "violates coding standards", I mean that my company likes to have the curly braces on their own lines.

Comment: OK I understand all the flames for thinking that 100% test code coverage is stupid - but I personally think its stupid that curly brackets are the only thing standing between you and 100% test code coverage.

Comment: The curly brace thing usually goes away when running the tests in Release mode, not on Debug mode. More specifically: when using the optimized code setting it will generate slightly different code, that eliminates the curly brace as an element from the analysis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within [NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=home) you have a method [`Assert.Throws<Exception>()`](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=exceptionAsserts&r=2.5), which checks if the desired exception was thrown. It also returns that exception as return value, so that you could have further assertations if you like:

```
[Test]
public void Api_GetDataUsingDataContractWithNullParameter_ThrowsArgumentNullException()
{
    var api = new Api();
    var exception = Assert.Throws<ArgumentNullException>(() => api.GetDataUsingDataContract(null));
    Assert.That(exception.Message, Is.Not.Null.Or.Empty);
    Assert.That(exception.Message, Is.StringContaining("source"));
}
```

Due to the fact, that the method does not throw by itself, your coverage would be 100%.

Answer (score 5):

Usually when people are measuring code coverage, they are looking at the code *covered by the tests* and not the tests themselves.

As this case shows, it doesn't really make sense to require *100% coverage on test units*.

The test is supposed to throw. That is what you are testing.

If you really want the entire method to be executed I guess you could test whether the exception was thrown manually. Something like this (haven't tested it, but I don't see why it shouldn't work):

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestNullComposite()
{
    IApi api = new Api();
    bool didThrow = false;
    try
    {
        api.GetDataUsingDataContract(null); // this method throws ArgumentNullException
    }
    catch(ArgumentNullException) 
    {
        didThrow = true;
    }
    Assert.IsTrue(didThrow);
}
```

But it seems like extra work for no good reason. I would suggest you re-evaluate your testing practices.

Comment: OK but then you don't have 100% branch coverage.  But I guess you did answer the base assumption - that 100% test code coverage is not any better than 99% if as Savanna points out, the only reason for not having 100% is the curly braces.

Comment: 100% is not necessary for your tests. What you have already is fine.

Answer (score 3):

What MAV is saying is true. Additionally, there is a way to exclude the test class from being analyzed from Code Coverage.

Just adorn your [TestClass] with the Attribute [[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd984116(v=vs.100).aspx)!

This way it is at least theoretically possible to reach 100% CC.

Answer (score 0):

Yes You Can But First You have to understand see assert throw will fully cover when

1. The expected exception match with the exception thrown by your function
   e.g

   assertThrows(NullPointerException.class,() -> userProfileService.getUserDetailById(userProfile.getAssociateId()));
2. When the expected and actual exception are not match or no any exception are thrown by assertthrow.
   Consider the above scenario example suppose called function will throw Other exception than NullPointerException then assertthrow will fail.

Now you have to think to fail and pass at the same time for assertthrow.

So a solution that I find is

```
userProfile = new UserProfile("101", "Amit Kumar Gupta", "amit@gmail.com", "Software Intern", "No",
                "999999999");
        userProfile2 = new UserProfile("102", "Satyam Sharma", "Satyam@gmail.com", "Software Engineer", "Yes",
                "8769356421");
        Mockito.when(userProfileDAO.findById(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(Optional.ofNullable(userProfile))
                .thenReturn(Optional.ofNullable(userProfile2));
List<Class<? extends Exception>> exceptionClassList = new ArrayList<Class<? extends Exception>>();
        exceptionClassList.add(NullPointerException.class);
        exceptionClassList.add(IllegalArgumentException.class);
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
            try {
                assertThrows(exceptionClassList.get(i),
                        () -> userProfileService.getUserDetailById(userProfile.getAssociateId()));
            } catch (AssertionError e) {
                assertNotNull(e.getMessage());
            }
        }
```

In this case Mockito will return two values and both will be used by function call inside the assertThrow first time assertThrow will match the expected exception i.e. NullPointerException.class

Second time assertThrow will Fail because the lambda function will not throw any exception but assertThrow is expecting a IllegalArgumentException.

It generates the AssertionError So that will caught by catch block.

Now You have 100% coverage.