# Why is Code Coverage not reporting 100% code coverage in test code when checking for exceptions?

Tags: c#, .net, code-coverage, mstest

Consider the following code:

```
public interface IConverter
{
}

public class ConverterFactory
{
    public IConverter GetConverter()
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class ConverterFactoryTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
    public void GetConverterShouldThrowExceptionWhenConverterNotRegistered()
    {
        var factory = new ConverterFactory();
        factory.GetConverter();
    }
}
```

Why is code coverage reporting that the test method is not 100% covered?

ANSWER:

The closing curly bracket is not covered as the code will always throw an exception and never get to the end of the method.

[How do I obtain 100% coverage when an exception is thrown in a unit test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090920/how-do-i-obtain-100-coverage-when-an-exception-is-thrown-in-a-unit-test?rq=1)

So it appears that to get 100% coverage you would need to exclude test methods that check exceptions. Annoying.

EDIT1: Removed fluent assertions as not relevant.
EDIT2: Removed generics as not relevant.

Comment: Out of curiosity, does it get picked up if you manually invoke the Action? Code coverage tools get lost when there is anything invoked on reflection or not called in your code specifically.

Comment: I updated the question, does not seem to be related to fluent assertions at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closing curly bracket is not covered as the code will always throw an exception and never get to the end of the method.

[How do I obtain 100% coverage when an exception is thrown in a unit test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090920/how-do-i-obtain-100-coverage-when-an-exception-is-thrown-in-a-unit-test?rq=1)

So it appears that to get 100% coverage you would need to exclude test methods that check exceptions. Annoying.

Answer (score 0):

convert the code into like below, of-course if it is one line.

```
public IConverter GetConverter() throw new ArgumentException();
```