# C#/XUint: Achieve 100% code coverage when testing an exception

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, code-coverage

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090920/how-do-i-obtain-100-coverage-when-an-exception-is-thrown-in-a-unit-test?rq=1); however, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24090920/how-do-i-obtain-100-coverage-when-an-exception-is-thrown-in-a-unit-test?rq=1) answer does not help me.

I have a test as the following:

```
[Fact]
public void NotImplementedComparison()
{
    // Arrange
    var f = new Foo();
    var b = new Bar();

    // Act
    Exception exception = Assert.Throws<NotImplementedException>((() => f.CompareTo(b)));

    // Assert
    Assert.Equal("Not implemented.", exception.Message);
}
```

When I analyze for test coverage in VS2017, it complains about `f.CompareTo(b)` as being not a covered block.

Comment: The final instructions in that anonymous method won't be executed because of the exception, so yes, part of that method won't be covered.

Comment: If you're referring to the `CompareTo` method; then I cover all the other parts of the method covered in other tests.

Comment: You might have to also test with other tools, such as OpenCover. I personally observed similar issues with Visual Studio, which shows its limitation.